# ranking across a column of a list

Tags: r, list, rank

I have a list with various symbols for which I want to create a column and rank a certain column relative to the rest of the list.

For example, I have a list `x` which contains the time series of `SPY` and `IWM`. for each list item I calculate `rsi`. I then want to create a new column in each list which assigns a rank to the lowest `rsi` value between `SPY` and `IWM`.

I always get a rank of 1, which cannot be correct, so something has to be wrong in my code. As I said, I need the rank of `rsi`.

```
library(quantmod)

stockData <- new.env() 

symbols = c("IWM","SPY")
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo',from = "2016-10-01",to = Sys.Date())


x <- list() 
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  x[[i]] <- get(symbols[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment 
  x[[i]]$rsi <-RSI(Cl(x[[i]]),14)
  x[[i]]$rank <- NA
  x[[i]]$rank<-apply(-x[[i]]$rsi,1,rank)
}
```

Comment: The `RSI` depends on 14 lagged values, implying that only after 14 observations, you will get an actual RSI-value. Therefore, you will have `NA`-values for the first 14 observations. This will mess with the rank. Do you want to ignore the first 14 observation when calculating the rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(quantmod)
stockData <- new.env() 

symbols = c("IWM","SPY")
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo',from = "2016-10-01",to = Sys.Date())

fulldata <- lapply(symbols, get, pos = stockData)
closedata <- lapply(fulldata, Cl)
rsi <- lapply(closedata, RSI, n = 14) # or e.g. n = 2, if RSI based on two periods
```

In order to use rank later on, we need to transform the data to a data.frame, because `rank()` doesn't like the class of the output that `RSI()` gives.

```
rsi <- lapply(rsi, as.data.frame)
```

`RSI()` depends on a moving average of 14 periods, causing the outcome for the first 14 periods to be `NA`, because no moving average could be calculated for them.

There are a couple of options to deal with the `NA`-values while doing the ranking. The option you find most suitable will depend on what you are going to use your data for later on:

- You can choose to replace all `NA`-values in `rsi` with zeros for the ranking:

  ```
  for(i in 1:length(rsi)){
      rsi[[i]][is.na(rsi[[i]])] <- 0
      }
  ranks <- lapply(rsi, rank)
  ```
- You can ignore all `NA`-value and simply remove them before ranking

  ```
   ranks <- lapply(rsi, rank, na.last = NA)
  ```
- Rank the `NA`-values as either the lowest or highest ranks.

  ```
  # If NA be put last, use "na.last = TRUE".
  # If NA be put first, use "na.last = FALSE"
  ranks <- lapply(rsi, rank, na.last = TRUE)
  ```

## Rank *among* symbols for a given day

I would combine the lists into one data frame and then calculate the row-wise rank:

```
rsiDF <- data.frame(rsi)
rsiDF <- cbind(rsiDF, t(apply(rsiDF, 1, rank)))
```

Note that here you can, again, decide how to deal with tied values and `NA`-values in your rank calculation (as described above and in `?rank`)

If you wish to turn it back into lists again:

```
k <- length(symbols)
interranks <- list()
for(i in 1:k){
   interranks[[i]] <- rsiDF[,c(i, i+k)]
}
```

Comment: Hi ken. Thank you for your help. You are correct in that rsi14 will give na. I  use longer time series so that wont be an issue. I will try your solution. It looks good and trying to get my head around it

Comment: Also ken. How do i add another column on each symbol of the list showing the rank of the symbol relative to the other symbols? For example if on day 1 the spy has a lower value than the equivalent day for iwm then spy gets rank1 and iwm gets rank 2

Comment: You were looking for the ranks among symbols all along, weren't you? That means I can delete the part on ranks in the bullet point, right?

Comment: great that is working for me Ken; i had to make adjustments though. Quick question: rsi <- lapply(closedata, RSI). how do you adjust the period of rsi? if for example i want to use period 2 ?again thanks loads for the help. greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just add `rsi <- lapply(closedata, RSI, n = 2)`. The default is n = 14